# Timer lable in the uitableviewcell in the UITableView overrides my timer lable so it runs speed , how to control the speed? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

My issue is i am having the `UITableViewCell` it contains one `UILable` and that is customized lable my `UITableView` have around 300 to 400 records. My requirement is i need to run the count down timer. The data is coming from service simultaneously i need to update the data in local.

Any solution for this would be highly appreciable...

**My code for Customized label:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TimLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *startTimer;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isDays;

-(void)configureTimeString:(NSString*)timeString;
- (void)startCounter;

@end


//
//  TimLabel.m
//  ap
//
//  Created by xxxxx on 06/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 xxx. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TimLabel.h"
@interface TimLabel ()
{
    int secondsLeft;

}
@end
@implementation TimLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code

//    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f animations:
//     ^{
//        [self setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
//    {
//        
//    }];
}
*/


-(void)configureTimeString:(NSString*)timeString
{
    NSArray * timerArray = [timeString componentsSeparatedByString:@":" ];
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
    hours = [[timerArray objectAtIndex:0 ] intValue];
    minutes = [[timerArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    seconds = [[timerArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
    secondsLeft =hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
//    if (!self.isDays) {
        [self startCounter];
//    }
}

- (void)startCounter
{
   self.startTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
    if (![self.startTimer isValid]) {
        [self.startTimer fire];
    }
}

-(void) updateCountdown
{
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
    secondsLeft--;
    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
    if (secondsLeft >= 0) {
        self.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    }
    else
    {
       [self.startTimer invalidate];
    }
     [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}



@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends finally i found the answer.

**Here is the answer:-**

**TimLable.h**

```
//
//  TimLabel.h
//  ap
//
//  Created by xxxx on 06/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 xxx. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TimLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *startTimer;

- (void)configureCountDownTimer:(NSDate *)closeDate;

@end
```

**TimLable.m**

```
//
//  TimLabel.m
//  ap
//
//  Created by xxxx on 06/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 xxx. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TimLabel.h"
@interface TimLabel ()
{
    int secondsLeft;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *closeDate;
@end
@implementation TimLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)configureCountDownTimer:(NSDate *)closeDate
{
    [self.startTimer invalidate];
    self.closeDate = closeDate;
    NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate toDate:closeDate options:0];

    if (components.day <= 0)
    {
        [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", components.hour, components.minute, components.second]];
    }
    else if(components.day == 1)
    {
        [self setText:@"1day"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ddays", components.day]];
    }

    if (!self.startTimer.isValid)
    {
        [self startCounter];
    }
}

- (void)updateCountdown
{
    NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate toDate:self.closeDate options:0];

    if (components.day <= 0)
    {
        if ((components.hour > 0)||(components.minute > 0)||(components.second > 0)) {
             [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", components.hour, components.minute, components.second]];
        }
        else
        {
            [self setText:@"Live"]; // This is for my functionality purpose
            [self.startTimer invalidate];
        }

    }
    else if(components.day == 1)
    {
        [self setText:@"1day"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ddays", components.day]];
//        NSLog(@"%d days",components.day);
    }
}


- (void)startCounter
{
   self.startTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
    if (![self.startTimer isValid]) {
        [self.startTimer fire];
    }
}



@end
```